# Difference between pageBuilder and transitionsBuilder typedef parameters of PageRouteBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, transition, flutter-animation

According to the [official docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageRouteBuilder/PageRouteBuilder.html) the `pageBuilder` parameter is used to build the primary route content and the `transitionsBuilder` parameter is used to build the route's transition.

So both of them have different jobs but if `pageBuilder` is use to build the primary route content then why it also declares two `Animation` parameter in its typedef [RoutePageBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RoutePageBuilder.html), also in the `transitionBuilder` typedef [RouteTransitionBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RouteTransitionsBuilder.html), there are two `Animation` parameters declared `animation` and `secondaryAnimation`.
What is the difference between those two `Animations` and how we can use them?

Comment: @pskink That didn't help!

Comment: @pskink What I have asked in Question!

Comment: @pskink That didn't fully answers my question, If we have `transitionsBuilder` for transition then why `pageBuilder` also supplies us with `Animation` ?

Comment: @pskink Both of the links doesn't explains about the use of those `Animation` parameters in `pageBuilders`

Comment: @pskink Tried but found nothing..ping me if you find something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs in routes.dart:

```
  /// [buildPage] is only called when the route is first built, and rarely
  /// thereafter. In particular, it is not automatically called again when the
  /// route's state changes unless it uses [ModalRoute.of]. For a builder that
  /// is called every time the route's state changes, consider
  /// [buildTransitions]. For widgets that change their behavior when the
  /// route's state changes, consider [ModalRoute.of] to obtain a reference to
  /// the route; this will cause the widget to be rebuilt each time the route
  /// changes state.
  ///
  /// In general, [buildPage] should be used to build the page contents, and
  /// [buildTransitions] for the widgets that change as the page is brought in
  /// and out of view. Avoid using [buildTransitions] for content that never
  /// changes; building such content once from [buildPage] is more efficient.

  /// The [buildTransitions] method, in contrast to [buildPage], is called each
  /// time the [Route]'s state changes (e.g. the value of [canPop]).
  ///
  /// The [buildTransitions] method is typically used to define transitions
  /// that animate the new topmost route's comings and goings. When the
  /// [Navigator] pushes a route on the top of its stack, the new route's
  /// primary [animation] runs from 0.0 to 1.0. When the Navigator pops the
  /// topmost route, e.g. because the use pressed the back button, the
  /// primary animation runs from 1.0 to 0.0.
```